# as3 - setting textures alpha-value

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, alpha-transparency

For an Actionscript 3 "drawing application", I want to be able to chose a Texture and set it's transparency.
Therefore I try to set the alpha-transparency of a texture.
But it's not working.

**What I do:**

1. At first I use graphics.linestyle() to set the lines thickness and ALPHA-value.
2. After that I (a) load a png, (b) read it's bitmapData and (c) then use it with lineBitmapStyle.

**Result:**

When drawing lines (with moveTo, lineTo, etc) the lines use the texture, but IGNORE THE "Alpha" which was set with lineStyle.

What am I doing wrong?

```
myLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, setTexture);        

setTexture(e:Event):void 
{
  e.currentTarget.removeEventListener(e.type, arguments.callee);

  //Try 1: Trying to set the Alpha-Trasparency with "lineStyle"-Command:
  myDrawContainer.graphics.lineBitmapStyle(5, 0xFF0000, 0,6);

  //Try 2: Trying to set the Alpha-Transparency by changing the Alpha-Value of the loaded content:
  myLoader.content.alpha = 0.6;

  //Getting the BitmapData of the Image:
  BitmapDataOfMyTexture = Bitmap(LoaderInfo(e.target).content).bitmapData

  //"Using" the TBitmapData as "Color/Texture" for my Drawing:
  myDrawContainer.graphics.lineBitmapStyle( BitmapDataOfMyTexture );

  //Test-Drawing:
  myDrawContainer.graphics.moveTo( 0, 0 );
  myDrawContainer.graphics.moveTo( 500, 500 ); //-> RESULT: Textured Line WITHOUT Transparency!
```

}

RESULT: I get a line which uses the texture but WITHOUT Transparency.

**(Update) THE SOLUTION:** (Thanks to DodgerThud)
For setting/changing the Alpha-Channel of a loaded image, you don't use "lineStyle" but...

1. Create a NEW colorTransform-object
2. Then set it's "alphaMultiplier"-attribute to the specific alphaChannel
3. And then apply this newly created colorTransform-Object to the loaded BitmapData, by using the "colorTransform"-Method of the loaded BitmapData.

BUT :

 
  This does NOT work with images that don't have an alpha-Channel or don't have their alpha-channel activated. Those images only get DARKER when lowering the alpha-Channel. In those cases you have to do this:

1. At FIRST I create NEW BitmapData-Object with "new", set its width and height to the width and height of the loaded Image and set it 3rd Argument to TRUE (= transparency: ON). So you got a "Container" which has transparency ACTIVATED.
2. Then you use "copyPixels" on this "Container"-Object to fill it with the pixels of the LOADED BitmapData-Object.
3. And right after this the above approach with the "colorTransform"-Object brings the expected result.

So HERE'S THE WORKING CODE:

```
myLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, setTexture);

setTexture(e:Event):void 
{
  e.currentTarget.removeEventListener(e.type, arguments.callee);

  //Getting the BitmapData of the Image:
  BitmapDataOfMyTexture = Bitmap(LoaderInfo(e.target).content).bitmapData

  //Create an ADDITIONAL BitmapData-Object with 3rd  
  //argument set to TRUE and with same width and height
  //as the LOADED image:
  var BMDContainerWithAlphaActivated:BitmapData;
  BMDContainerWithAlphaActivated = new BitmapData(BitmapDataOfMyTexture.width, BitmapDataOfMyTexture.height, true, 0xFFFFFF);

  //Copy the pixels of the loaded image into the newly created 
  //"BitmapData-Container with activated AlphaChannel":
  BMDContainerWithAlphaActivated.copyPixels(BitmapDataOfMyTexture, new Rectangle(0, 0, BitmapDataOfMyTexture.width, BitmapDataOfMyTexture.height), new Point(0,0))

  //Modify the Alpha-Value (of the NEW BitmapData-Object):
  var colorChanges:ColorTransform = new ColorTransform();
      colorChanges.alphaMultiplier = 0.3;
  BMDContainerWithAlphaActivated.colorTransform(new Rectangle(0, 0, BitmapDataOfMyTexture.width, BitmapDataOfMyTexture.height), colorChanges);  


  //"Using" the (NEW) BitmapData as "Color/Texture" for my Drawing:
  myDrawContainer.graphics.lineBitmapStyle( BMDContainerWithAlphaActivated );

  //Test-Drawing:
  myDrawContainer.graphics.moveTo( 0, 0 );
  myDrawContainer.graphics.moveTo( 500, 500 ); //-> RESULT: Textured Line WITH Transparency 0.3!        
}
```

Comment: could you please post the actual (relevant) code, that would help us help you far better, imo.

Comment: Ok! I'll post the code (see above)!

Comment: Alright, I think the issue is the following. Changing the alpha value of `myLoader.content` will not change the properties of the `bitmapdata` of the loaded png file. You are merely changing the flash internal alpha value of the object. So when you are passing the content of the loaded file, it still has the same bitmapdata as before. Now, I have a question, why not simply set the alpha value of myDrawContainer directly to the value you need, like `myDrawContainer.alpha = 0.6`?

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't solve the problem, because this gives you just ONE Alpha-Setting for the WHOLE drawing. BUT: When drawing a line with a "normal" color (using "lineStyle") you are able to draw a line/path with a lot of DIFFERENT Alpha-Settings (by applying different "lineStyle"-Commands for each segment of the line just before drawing the specific segment). And that's exactely what I need to do here. I need to draw textured lines/paths with DIFFERENT Alpha-Settings for DIFFERENT segments of the line. Any other proposal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah I see, this is a bit more complex than I initially thought.

Alright, looking at the [documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Graphics.html#lineBitmapStyle()) for `lineBitmapStyle` shows me that the function expects the following parameters: `lineBitmapStyle(bitmap:BitmapData, matrix:Matrix = null, repeat:Boolean = true, smooth:Boolean = false)`

Now, matrix, repeat and smooth will not help us here (matrix is used here for transformation, i.e. positioning, rotation etc.), but bitmap:BitmapData might. What we need to do is manipulate the BitmapData of the loaded PNG file before passing it to `lineBitmapStyle`. Sadly we cannot set the alpha value directly on the BMD, so we can try to `colorTransform` it.

This is untested code, but I think it is the right approach:

```
..
//store the bitmapdata in a seperate local variable
var bmd:BitmapData = LoaderInfo(e.target).content;
//create a ColorTransform Object to change the values of the BMD
var cTransform:ColorTransform = new ColorTransform();
//now here I am unsure, manipulating the alpha value of the BMD
cTransform.alphaMultiplier = 0.6;
//defining the rectangle dimensions of the bmd, we want it to be over the entire texture
var rect:Rectangle = new Rectangle(0,0,bmd.width,bmd.height);
//apply the colorTransformation on the BMD
bmd.colorTransform(rect,cTransform);
...
//the now manipulated BMD gets set as lineBitmapStyle
myDrawContainer.graphics.lineBitmapStyle(bmd);
```

And now that I think about it, maybe we can workaround setting the alpha value on the BMD, by creating a Bitmap first, set the alpha value there and use the bitmapdata of the Bitmap instead. Like this:

```
var bmd:BitmapData = LoaderInfo(e.target).content;
var bm:Bitmap = new Bitmap(bmd);
bm.alpha = 0.6;
myDrawContainer.graphics.lineBitmapStyle(bm.bitmapData);
```

---

Alright, the first snippet from above seems to be the way to do it, but the `transparent` value of the BitmapData needs to be true. Given that you do not directly create the BitmapData yourself and the value is false, we have quite a tricky situation here.

Another approach would be to create an additional bitmapdata that allows for transparancy and `draw()` the bitmapdata of the loaded image on it:

```
var bmdSource:BitmapData = LoaderInfo(e.target).content;
var bmd:BitmapData = new BitmapData(bmdSource.width, bmdSource.height,true,0xffffffff);
var cTransform:ColorTransform = new ColorTransform();
cTransform.alphaMultiplier = 0.6;
var rect:Rectangle = new Rectangle(0,0,bmd.width,bmd.height);
bmd.colorTransform(rect,cTransform);
//now we have a completely white bitmapdata bmd, with an alpha value of 0.6
//we draw the contents of the bmdSource onto bmd, the alpha value effect should carry over
bmd.draw(bmdSource);
```

Comment: Unfortunately both approaches don't work. The second one doesn't seem to have ANY effect. The first one makes the texture DARKER (lower alpha-value = darker texture). Any idea why.

Comment: Hmm sorry no. Could you please trace the property `transparent` on `bmd` following right after the creation of `bmd`from my snippet. It's a read only property, but this will tell us if the bitmapdata even supports transparency at all.

Comment: We seem to come close: When I trace this it returns FALSE. So the bitmapdata doesn't seem to support transparency yet. But I don't know a way to "activate" transparency. I know that I can apply transparency when creating a bitmapdata-object with "new" (=> new bitmapdata(width, height, true). But as you can see in my code, I don't create the bitmap-data-object with "new" but by returning the bitmapdata from Bitmap(LoaderInfo(e.target).content).bitmapData. -> And the returning BitmapData...

Comment: ...has transparency turned OFF (Maybe the pictures I use have no transparency YET. But as I said: I want to be able to set transparency, even on pictures that have NO transparency yet.) So is there a way to "activate" transparency?? Or can I create a NEW (empty) bitmap with "new" and then ADD the content of Bitmap(LoaderInfo(e.target).content).bitmapData to this without overwriting the transpareny-activated bitmapdata-object??

Comment: You could try adding an alpha channel to the png. One way that I usually use is with the program Gimp, open the picture there, then press `layer` -> `transparency` -> `add alpha channel`. after that, save over the file with `file`-> `export as` and see if the `transparent` value has changed to true. Otherwise, I'm kinda stumped on how to activate the transparency on a loaded Bitmap, but I will keep looking around

Comment: I added another approach to my answer, please try and see if this solves the problem.

Comment: Well I got some good news and some bad news! The bad news is: Your approach generally would work, but doesn't work in my specific case: Because as I said it is a drawing application. So the USER of this drawing application will decide which picture to use. // The GOOD NEWS is: I found the solution: At FIRST I create NEW BitmapData-Object with "new", set its width and height to the width and height of the loaded Image and set it 3rd Argument to TRUE (= transparency: ON). So I got a "Container" which has transparency ACTIVATED. => And then I use "copyPixels" on this "Container"-Object to fill...

Comment: ...it with the pixels of the LOADED BitmapData-Object. => And right after this YOUR approach with the "colorTransform"-Object brings the expected result. So thank you very much for helping me out. I'm going to update my question with the solution and vote for your answer after that!! Thanks again!

Comment: No problem, I'm glad that I could help out.